# WARNING: The predicate =/2 is unknown

Tags: iso-prolog, tuprolog

I'm trying to transfer a file written for SICStus Prolog into TuProlog.

I get the error message:

> WARNING: The predicate =/2 is unknown.

(The code works in SICStus, but not in TuProlog).

What should I use instead of `=/2` for TuProlog? What is the difference in syntax?

Comment: The standard `=/2` predicate is supported by tuProlog. What's the context for that error message?

Comment: I get the warning message in the 'Debug information' of the tuProlog IDE.

Comment: No information on the **calling** context for the `=/2` predicate?

Comment: I wrote a program to find the best move in a game of chess - the predicate 'best_move' should always succeed (and it does in SICStus), but a lot of the time it fails in tuProlog. Whenever it fails, I get the error message ' =/2 predicate is unknown'. I don't know how to determine which line of code is causing the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: TuProlog being not much ISO conforming, simply add the fact `=(X,X).`